# Problem related with univalent function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck with the following problem:

As [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univalent_function)  says : "In mathematics, in the branch of complex analysis, a holomorphic function on an open subset of the complex plane is called univalent if it is one-to-one." A related example is :

> Any mapping $\phi_a$ of the open unit disc to itself : 
>   $$\phi_a(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\bar a z}\,\,\,\text{where}\,\,|a| \leq 1$$
>   is $\color{red}{\text{univalent}}$.

According to the definition,to be univalent $\phi_a(z)$ has to one-one. But if I take $a=1,$then for $z_1 \neq z_2,\,\,\,\text{where}\,\,z_1,z_2 \,\,\text{are any 2 points in the open unit disc,}$ we see $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$.

So, How this function can be 1-1. Where I went wrong? Can someone help me? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: The inequality ought to be $\lvert a\rvert < 1$. For $\lvert a \rvert = 1$, $\phi_a$ is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer said, the inequality should have been $|a|<1$. I edited the article.